# Interpreting CPU BenchMark for Multi Core Systems

Tags: cpu, multi-core, benchmarking

What is the standard ways (if any) to interpret the results of cpu benchmarking for multicore systems relative to single core systems?  I am trying to compare the Passmark result of AMD 64 Vs AMD 64x2.  But since in theory performance should be related to how many tasks are made parallel.  If there is only 1 active thread running, a single core system should be similar to a multicore system.

So under what conditions are those benchmarks done?